# Django convert JSON to CSV

Tags: python, json, django, csv

I am working on a function to load data from Data SF and download it as a CSV. I can make a query to their database and accurately display the results in a template, but I cannot write those results to a CSV. I've been reading online about issues converting JSON to CSV, but I can't seem to connect them to my project.

The code from this view will make a query and display the results in a template:

```
if request.POST:
    qAddress = request.POST.get('qAddress')
    url = 'https://data.sfgov.org/resource/2zah-tuvt.json?qAddress=%s' % qAddress
    search_request = requests.get(url, verify=False)
    search_results = search_request.json()
    args = {'url': url, 'search_results': search_results}
    args.update(csrf(request))
    return render(request, 'sts_soda_search_results.html', args)
```

However, this code fails:

```
if request.POST:
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/csv')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="Search Results.csv"'
    url = request.POST.get('url')
    search_request = requests.get(url, verify=False)
    search_results = search_request.json()
    writer = csv.writer(response)
    writer.writerow(['Tree ID', 'Species', 'DBH', 'Address', 'Latitude', 'Longitude'])
    for obj in search_results:
        writer.writerow([obj.treeid, obj.qspecies, obj.dbh, obj.qaddress, obj.latitude, obj.longitude])
    return response
```

I instead get this error: 
'dict' object has no attribute 'treeid'

replacing writer.writerow([obj.treeid....]) with writer.writeror(obj.values()) works, but is inconsistent since some queries have additional fields that I don't want to include.

json.loads(), json.load() and json.dumps() don't return the query, so is there a way to make it work with using .json() and convert the results to an instance that csv writer can process? I'm confused as to why it works in a template but not in csv writer.

Comment: When accessing dictionaries, you need to do `obj['treeid'], obj['qspecies']...` See this: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries

Comment: Django templates transparently rewrite things to make dot notation work in many places where it wouldn't ordinarily work. So you can access a dictionary using dct.key and you can access a list using lst.123, but this is not actual python, this is just template syntax sugar. In real code you need to do dct['key'] and lst[123].

Comment: thanks! I had been trying obj[treeid] and that was failing and i hadn't noticed the lack of quotation marks. I'll add the answer and sign it off. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Answered by BorrajaX and Mad Wombat in the comments to my original question, the problem was that I was incorrectly referring to the dict keys. The working code:

```
if request.POST:
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/csv')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="Search Results.csv"'
    url = request.POST.get('url')
    search_request = requests.get(url, verify=False)
    search_results = search_request.json()
    writer = csv.writer(response)
    writer.writerow(['Tree ID', 'Species', 'DBH', 'Address', 'Latitude', 'Longitude'])
    for obj in search_results:
        writer.writerow([obj['treeid'], obj['qspecies'], obj['dbh'], obj['qaddress'], obj['latitude'], obj['longitude']])
    return response
```